# what is the best lightweight monitoring system run under nginx?

Tags: monitoring, nginx

I want to monitor my small vps node; presently serving by nginx. I do not want to use apache2; presently considering monitorix, suggest me the best lightweight monitoring system run under nginx  ?

Comment: What do you want to monitor?

Comment: diskusage, process, nginx, network, io, threads, memory usage, and cpu usage(munin fits but needs light weight one which runs under nginx).

Answer (score 2):

I've previously had experience deploying Munin. It's fairly good if you want to track the basics (CPU/Disk IO/RAM/Network IO) and you can extend it if you want.

It generates static HTML files in `/var/cache/munin/www` that you can just point nginx at.

It's pretty much as simple as that but you can also have Munin monitor the status of nginx. [This tutorial](http://blog.nragaz.com/post/3966431477/setting-up-munin-to-monitor-ubuntu-server) as as good as any of the others.

Comment: i am also considering munin; since i am going use samll vps , cpu/memory usage are noticeable/huge ?

Comment: "Noticeable" is relative. Try it. Takes about 20 seconds to install and you'll be able to see how much RAM it uses and *then* decided if it's for you. My opinion of how it runs on my not-small VPS isn't going to help you much.